# How to avoid using Listener on Android - Java

Tags: java, android, class, static

I'm trying to get the `last user's position` but I'm in a static context.

Here's the code

```
public void getLastKnownLocation() {
    FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.
            getFusedLocationProviderClient(App.getContext());

    fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
            .addOnSuccessListener(**activity_needed_here**, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                    // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
                    if (location != null) {
                        System.out.println("Speed is " + location.getSpeed());
                    }
                }
            });
```

The problem is that I'm in a static context and I cannot have an activity here to call. I can, however, access the `app context`.

How can I avoid using the `addOnSuccessListener` or how can I implement this in a static context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the `Task` JavaDocs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task), there are three forms of `addOnSuccessListener()`. You could consider using [the one that does not take an `Activity` as the first parameter](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task?hl=en#addOnSuccessListener(com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener%3C?%20super%20TResult%3E)).

Comment: Thanks! Can I ask you one last question? If i want my `getLastKnownLocation()` static class function to return the `Location` object, I cannot do that inside the `addOnSuccessListener` as it says: `unexpected return value`. How can I return a value there?

Comment: @SelnWind12: That is not possible. Your `static` `getLastKnownLocation()` method needs to take some sort of listener object that you can call from `onSuccess()`. Alternatively, if you are using things like RxJava, I think there are adapter libraries that can convert the `Task` that you get back from `fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()` into something like an RxJava `Single`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. So I could attach a listener the the `onSuccess()` function to return a parameter into my static class function `getLastKnownLocation`? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

you can change the code to export this listener, example:

```
public Task<Location> getLastKnownLocation() {
    FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.
            getFusedLocationProviderClient(App.getContext());

    return fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
```

And when you call getLastKnownLocation, should do:

```
getLastKnownLocation().addOnSuccessListener(....).addOnFailureListener(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just want to share some idea about how to make `getLastKnownLocation()` to return `Location` object directly in Java, that the OP asked in the comment section in the recommened answer.

---

I will use `AlertDialog` and `onDismissListener` as an example here.

Let's say after a dialog has been dismissed, it needs to return a value back to the caller:

```
public void showDialog() {
   boolean readyToDoNextStep = false;

   AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                            .setTitle("title")
                            .setMessage("message")
                            .setOnDismissListener(dialog -> {
                                readyToDoNextStep = true; // <= update flag and return to caller!                    
                             });
}
```

The first way I will use is to pass an Interface to it (which is still not the OP wants :) )

```
public interface DismissCallback {
   void isReady(boolean flag);
}

public void showDialog(DismissCallback cb) {
   boolean readyToDoNextStep = false;

   AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                            .setTitle("title")
                            .setMessage("message")
                            .setOnDismissListener(dialog -> {
                                readyToDoNextStep = true;
                                cb.isReady(readyToDoNextStep); // <= call callback method                    
                             });
}

public void main() {
   showDialog((flag) -> { //flag == true here  });
}
```

The second way is to use `Future` and `thread synchronization`.
The idea is to use `thread synchronization` to collect the result from the listener and then return the results to `Future`.

The calling will be as simple as boolean `shallGoToNextStep = showDialog(context)` but you can see that the implementation will be more complicated. Especially I am using an UI component and its listener as an example so I need be-aware which thread I am at.

```
// For thread synchronization
public static class ReadyCallback {
     boolean complete = false;
     Boolean readyToDoNextStep = false;
}


// Return boolean directly here
// This shall be run on worker thread or else the main thread will be loop to dead
    public boolean showDialog(Context context) {
        ReadyCallback cb = new ReadyCallback();
        Future<Boolean> future = Executors.newCachedThreadPool().submit(() -> {
            ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context).execute(() -> {
                AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                        .setTitle("title")
                        .setMessage("message")
                        .setOnDismissListener(dialog -> {
                            cb.complete = true;
                            cb.readyToDoNextStep = true;
                            synchronized (cb) {
                                cb.notifyAll();
                            }
                        }).create();
                ad.show();
            });

            // while loop - until cb.complete is marked to true
            while (!cb.complete) {
                synchronized (cb) {
                    cb.wait();
                }
            }

            // return status
            return cb.readyToDoNextStep;
        });

        try {
            return future.get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: For Kotlin, I believe can rely on `Coroutines` to achieve the same result.